# No newline when opening double curly braces in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I am creating new function using PhpStorm but when I open new braces it looks like that:

[image]

When I actually want it to create new indented line like this:

[image]

I searched a lot but nothing worked for me and here is my settings page

[image]

Comment: So ... how do you create such new function -- from code completion, some live template (exisitng or your own) etc ?

Comment: This issue that when type { and it looks like that {|} when | is my cursor what i need is when i hit enter it create new shifted line instead of 
{
}

Comment: Well -- it work just fine here .. so must be your settings indeed. 1) Try switching to Default scheme first; See if it does any better; 2) If not -- then try `Set from...` and choose `PSR1/PSR2` (for example). 3) If still the same -- then it must be something else -- maybe something at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Smart Keys` -- possibly `Smart indent` option (sorry, I have almost all of them enabled since the beginning .. so not sure if they come disabled by default or not and stuff like that)